# How to use scraping to crawl datas from multipages?

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to use **scrape** to get datas from multipages.The start urls is

> `https://gold.jgi.doe.gov/projects?page=1&Project.Project+Name=man&count=25`

And I don't know how to add 1 once a time to the url attribute "page".

I've tried to add all the urls to the variable "start_urls",the code as below:

```
from scrapy.spiders import Spider,Request
from scrapy.selector import Selector

from dirbot.items import GenDis


class GDSpider(Spider):
    name = "GenDis"
    allowed_domains = ["gold.jgi.doe.gov"]
    item = []
    for i in range(1,10):
        url = "https://gold.jgi.doe.gov/projects?page="+str(i)+"&Project.Project+Name=man&count=25"
        item.append(url)

    start_urls = item
    print start_urls


     def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        sites = sel.xpath('//tr[@class="odd"]|//tr[@class="even"]')
        items = []

        for site in sites:
            item = GenDis()
            item['Id'] = site.xpath('td/a/text()').extract()
            item['Link'] = site.xpath('td/a/@href').extract()
            item['Name'] = map(unicode.strip, site.xpath('td[2]/text()').extract())
            item['Status'] = map(unicode.strip, site.xpath('td[3]/text()').extract())
            item['Add_Date'] = map(unicode.strip, site.xpath('td[4]/text()').extract())
            items.append(item)
            return items
```

But there is a problem that I can only get one data from each page,but there is 25 datas in each page.
So can anyone tell me what the problem is or tell me how to add 1 each time to the base url.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `yield items` instead of `return items`. The return ends your for loop but yield is a generator and allows the for loop to continue.

Also remove references to `items` in your for loop and just `yield item` otherwise the `items` object will be yielded multiple times with a growing list of repeated items in it.

Comment: I've tried yield,and there is an error ERROR: **Spider must return Request, BaseItem, dict or None,** if I use yield instead of return

Comment: Check that the statement is `yield item` and not `yield items`. Otherwise that's odd because `item` should descend from `BaseItem`. Could you show us the declaration of GenDis() please.

Comment: I've solve the problem.It's just because the statement is **yield items**.Thanks a lot